# getMap() not returning token

Tags: google-earth-engine

My script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/03072a1aa4dd0c8bcb5f0d6f50840cc7

This function used to return a token. Now token is empty and from what I can remember the mapId used to look different as well.

This is what `getMap()` gives me:

```
{
  "mapid": "projects/earthengine-legacy/maps/6549925a95e57c05d203d65bc6820c40-e563a4b747bc6703107afb69bbe17a7e",
  "token": "",
  "image": ...image stuff
}
```

How should i format my tile url now?

Answer (score 1):

In order to automatically provide the tile url for any x, y and z, you could use a regex replacement:

```
var tile = img
    .getMap({min: 0.0, max: 9000, bands: ['B8', 'B11', 'B4']});

// we hardcode x, y and z
var url = ee.data.getTileUrl(tile, 123, 4567, 8)

// replace hardcoded x, y and z for a generic tile position
url = url.replace("/tiles/8/123/4567?", "/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?")
```

Now, you can use the url in any tile reader. I also found out that you may need to use a referer, if you will display the tile in a tool such as QGIS. The referer is the link that you get by clicking on `GetLink` button.

Comment: The GEE team has provided a new way of generating image tiles: `image.getMapId(vis_params)['tile_fetcher'].url_format`. You can find an example of this usage in this notebook provided by GEE: https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/examples/ipynb/TF_demo1_keras.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

The docs have no yet updated to reflect a comming change, see group post [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-earth-engine-developers/j9fhrCL2lh8/Q1S-vJUfAQAJ)

For now use `ee.data.getTileUrl()` together with `getMap()`. For example:

```
print(ee.data.getTileUrl(img.getMap({min:0, max: 3000}), 9014,4817, 14))
```

The tile in the example is just some random tile that covers the area I'm interested in. The function call above will give you a url like this:

```
https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/earthengine-legacy/maps/<Map ID>/tiles/14/9014/4817?key=<KEY>
```

Remove the `key` query string and change the tile to the template values, like so:

```
https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/earthengine-legacy/maps/<Map ID>/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}
```

You now have a working tile url.