# Trouble plotting Earth Engine images with Folium using Python

Tags: leaflet, google-earth-engine, tiles, folium, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am trying to plot an earth engine image using Python and the Folium package as described in the [Python docs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/python_install-colab#interactive_map) for Earth Engine. I tried running the example code given and I can't seem get the image to show up when saving as an HTML and opening in the browser. The getMapID() method always returns a token as empty string as in: `mapID['token'] = ''`. Does anyone know a way to get Earth Engine map tiles to show up on a Folium interactive map?

I also tried using the [folium_gee functions](https://github.com/mccarthyryanc/folium_gee) by mccarthyryanc and ran into the same issues, the basemap shows up but not the tiles.

```py
# Import libraries.
import ee
import folium

# Initialize the Earth Engine library.
ee.Initialize()

# Define a method for displaying Earth Engine image tiles to folium map.
def add_ee_layer(self, eeImageObject, visParams, name):
  mapID = ee.Image(eeImageObject).getMapId(visParams)
  folium.raster_layers.TileLayer(
    tiles = "https://earthengine.googleapis.com/map/"+mapID['mapid']+
      "/{z}/{x}/{y}?token="+mapID['token'],
    attr = "Map Data © Google Earth Engine",
    name = name,
    overlay = True,
    control = True
  ).add_to(self)

# Add EE drawing method to folium.
folium.Map.add_ee_layer = add_ee_layer

# Fetch an elevation model.
dem = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003')

# Set visualization parameters.
visParams = {'min':0, 'max':3000, 'palette':['225ea8','41b6c4','a1dab4','ffffcc']}

# Create a folium map object.
myMap = folium.Map(location=[20, 0], zoom_start=3, height=500)

# Add the elevation model to the map object.
myMap.add_ee_layer(dem, visParams, 'DEM')

# Add a layer control panel to the map.
myMap.add_child(folium.LayerControl())

# Display the map.
myMap.save("myMap.html")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the URL format is a little different than what is posted in the docs currently. The code above gives a url string of:

```
https://earthengine.googleapis.com/map/projects/earthengine-legacy/maps/<Map Id>/{z}/{x}/{y}?token=
```

Which I believe from this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/336614/getmap-not-returning-token) is depreciated and the url no longer needs the token. If instead you use the command:

```
ee.data.getTileUrl(image.getMapId({visParams}), 8014,4817, 37)
```

You get something like:

```
https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/earthengine-legacy/maps/<Map Id #>/tiles/37/8014/4817
```

where the (x,y,z) values are arbitrary, if you then replace "37/8014/4817" with "{z}/{x}/{y}" to get:

```
https://earthengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/earthengine-legacy/maps/<Map Id #>/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}
```

is a valid URL and can plot with folium's TileLayer class. This definition of adding a layer to the folium map worked for me.

```py
def add_ee_layer(self, eeImageObject, visParams, name):
  tiles = ee.data.getTileUrl(eeImageObject.getMapId(visParams), 8014, 4817, 37)
  tiles = tiles[:-12] + "{z}/{x}/{y}"
  folium.raster_layers.TileLayer(
    tiles = tiles,
    attr = "Map Data © Google Earth Engine",
    name = name,
    overlay = True,
    control = True
  ).add_to(self)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the current recommended method for defining the `tiles` argument is as follows:

```py
# Define a method for displaying Earth Engine image tiles to folium map.
def add_ee_layer(self, eeImageObject, visParams, name):
  map_id_dict = ee.Image(eeImageObject).getMapId(visParams)
  folium.raster_layers.TileLayer(
    tiles = map_id_dict['tile_fetcher'].url_format,
    attr = "Map Data &copy; <a href='https://earthengine.google.com/'>Google Earth Engine</a>",
    name = name,
    overlay = True,
    control = True
  ).add_to(self)
```

I see you found a workaround, but does this resolve your issue as well?

Comment: PS: the Developer Guide is being updated to reflect the change.